# shm_open shared memory across programs

Tags: c, shared-memory

I am building 3 multithreaded programs with pthread that need access to the same shared memory.

I have one program called parent that will create the shared memory and the other two, the children. I have been able to get the parent working with two threads, one that has a cond_wait and the other broadcasts. Then I went on to try and get it working with one of the children. I copied the code for the cond_wait thread to the child and tried to run it, but have had no luck.

This is because the child is not able to use the shared memory, I'm pretty certain it is because of how I create the shared object in the parent in the child but I have been stuck for a couple of hours and am not sure what to try now.

The parent uses this code to make the shared memory

```
bool create_shared_object( shared_memory_t* shm) {
    const char* share_name = shared_memory_name;
    shm_unlink(share_name);
    shm->name = share_name;

    shm->fd = shm_open(shm->name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL  | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);    

    if(shm->fd == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "shm_open(%s): %s (%d)\n", shm->name, strerror(errno), errno);

        return false;
    }

    if (ftruncate(shm->fd , MEMORY_SIZE)){
        fprintf(stderr, "ftruncate(%s): %s (%d)\n", shm->name, strerror(errno), errno);

        return false;
    }

    shm = mmap(NULL, MEMORY_SIZE,
        PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm->fd, 0);
    if (shm == MAP_FAILED){
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap(%s, %zu): %s (%d)\n", shm->name, (size_t)MEMORY_SIZE, strerror(errno), errno);

        return false;     
    }   
    return true;
}
```

And this is what the child is using to open the object

```
bool create_shared_object( shared_memory_t* shm) {
    const char* share_name = shared_memory_name;

    shm->name = share_name;

    shm->fd = shm_open(shm->name, O_RDWR, 0);
    if(shm->fd == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "shm_open(%s): %s (%d)\n", shm->name, strerror(errno), errno);

        return false;
    }
    

    shm = mmap(NULL, MEMORY_SIZE,
        PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm->fd, 0);
    if (shm == MAP_FAILED){
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap(%s, %zu): %s (%d)\n", shm->name, (size_t)MEMORY_SIZE, strerror(errno), errno);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

For reference I define shm like this in each file  `shared_memory_t shm;`
And this is the structure of shared_memory_t

```
typedef struct shm{
    const char* name;

    int fd;

    shared_parking_t data;
}shared_memory_t;
```

The result of `ls -l /dev/shm` shows the corresponding memory file:

```
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 cab403 cab403 584 Sep 26 23:27 PARKING
```

If anyone can lend a hand I would be quite grateful

edit* I am not sure if this is important but I am using Linux

edit 2 I am checking if the child can use the shared memory by printing in a loop the value in the memory the parent changes. In this test the child only has open_shared_object and the printing for loop

edit 3 I have updated my code based on input from answers

Comment: When you speak about child, you mean a fork()? Have you a father and a child? How do you ensure the child does not start before the father? The father creates the shm before forking? Or both are accessing the shm concurrently without synchronization? In that case the child may create/access the segment before the father but it does not call ftruncate().

Comment: @RachidK. When i talk about parent and child its more of a reference to the parent being the provider of the shared memory. Since the parent is its own program i just run it before the child

Comment: So you have two programs : one called the parent, runs before the other program called the child?

Comment: The real names of the program is simulator (parent) and manger(child). But yeah atm i just run the programs in the order parent then child, so the order is correct

Comment: Do you see the entry created in /dev/shm? Update your post if necessary with "ls -l /dev/shm"

Comment: Sorry I am still new to c. How do i check /dev/shm? and what do you mean by update my post?

Comment: As the code snippet does not print anything in the error branches (only false is returned), where do you get a failure? shm_open(), ftruncate(), mmap() ?

Under the shell where you run your program, enter : ls -l /dev/shm

Comment: Ah ok yeah lmao i should have known what you meant with ls. When i use that command i get ```-rwxr-xr-x 1 cab403 cab403 584 Sep 26 23:27 PARKING``` There are no errors i have everything in a `if(open_shared_object(&shm))` I do have a print outside of the if to let me know if it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some debug prints in the error branches to know which system call fails. For example:

```c
#include <errno.h>

shm->fd = shm_open(shm->name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
if(shm->fd == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "shm_open(%s): %s (%d)\n", shm->name, strerror(errno), errno);
    return false;
}

if (ftruncate(shm->fd , MEMORY_SIZE)){
    fprintf(stderr, "ftruncate(%s): %s (%d)\n", shm->name, strerror(errno), errno);
    return false;
}

shm = mmap(NULL, MEMORY_SIZE,
    PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm->fd, 0);
if (shm == MAP_FAILED) {
    fprintf(stderr, "mmap(%s, %zu): %s (%d)\n", shm->name, (size_t)MEMORY_SIZE, strerror(errno), errno);
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Do the same in the child...

Moreover, the code is incoherent as you pass `shm` of type `shared_memory_t` and you overwrite it with the mapped region?!? It should be:

```c
[...]
shm->data = mmap(NULL, MEMORY_SIZE,
        PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm->fd, 0);
if (shm->data == MAP_FAILED){
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap(%s, %zu): %s (%d)\n", shm->name, (size_t)MEMORY_SIZE, strerror(errno), errno);

        return false;
    }
[...]
```

Comment: Cheers for your answer for how to actually add error messages for this code. Unfortunately there is no errors. I have also updated my code based on all the input i have been given

Comment: @ClueLess: I updated the answer. The issue may come from the shm = mmap() ==> Should be shm->data = mmap() ?

Answer (score 1):

First, why do you use `O_CREAT` flag on child? It should open an existing area, not create a new one.

Secondly, have you made sure that your shared regions have same name and the name starts with `/` and there is no name collisions?

Third, I don't think child should feed in the `mode` parameter as they are not creating the area.

Also, you could have `O_EXCL` flag in the parent just to make sure that you have created a new area and not just opened an old one.

Comment: Yeah you have a good point about the `O_CREAT`. Yeah both are using the same name with a `/`.By mode parameter in the child do you mean ```S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO```? Would i just null this instead

Comment: I have made all of these changes without any luck. With mode, null mode and 0 in mode. Any chance you have any other ideas what might be going wrong?